# Detect time between two 24 hour time format?

Tags: sql, sql-server

write simple this query:

```
select 'yes' where cast('18:00:00' as time) between cast('17:00:00' as time) and cast('06:00:00' as time)
```

the time `18:00:00`  between `17:00:00 PM` and `06:00:00 Am` but dont print yes message,how can i check that time ?

Comment: Because, for the clause you have, it isn't. A `time` only supports the 24 clock; it doesn't have awareness of days. Your clause is effectively `WHERE '18:00:00' >= '17:00:00' AND '18:00:00' <= '06:00:00'` and `'18:00:00'` *is not* less than `'06:00:00'`.

Comment: It's `or` and not `and`, no?

Comment: `BETWEEN` doesn't support `OR`, no @SteveC .

Comment: My answer got rid of between.  between is not appropriate here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to check if 18:00 is between time1 and time2, and they *could be* on the opposite side of midnight. The logic is simple:

```
if time1 <= time2 then
    check if 18:00 >= time1 and 18:00 <= time2
else
    check if 18:00 >= time1 or  18:00 <= time2
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not an obvious solution, but what you could do is check if the value is `BETWEEN` the start and end time, or if the start time is *after* the end time, check if the time is *after* the start time *or* `BETWEEN` midnight and the end time:

```sql
DECLARE @StartTime time(0) = '17:00:00',
        @EndTime time(0) = '06:00:00',
        @CheckTime time(0) = '18:00:00';

SELECT 'Yes'
WHERE (@CheckTime BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime AND @StartTime < @EndTime)
   OR (@StartTime >= @EndTime AND (@CheckTime >= @StartTime OR @CheckTime BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND @EndTime));
```